# Sitecore computed index fields - how to store untokenized

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8, sitecore8.1, sitecore-lucene

Sitecore 8.1 with default lucene. I'm using a custom index with a computed field to store the true values of a multilist field, rather than the guids. This works and I can see within the Luke tool that the field are indexed as text.

Some of the values contain spaces, but I want these to be indexed as the whole field. The problem is these are being indexed in a tokenized fashion, so for example 'Little Hampton' is being indexed as 'Little' and 'Hampton'.

How do I get computed fields to be stored untokenized? See the raw:AddComputedIndexField section:

```xml
<indexConfigurations>
    <myCustomIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
    <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
    <analyzer ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
    <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
        <!-- you must have _uniqueid or you wont be able to update the document later -->
            <field fieldName="_uniqueid" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
            </field>
            <field fieldName="title" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
            <field fieldName="summary" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="YES" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />  
        </fieldNames>
    </fieldMap>
    <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
        <!-- resolves selected guids to text values -->
        <field storageType="NO" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" fieldName="my multilist field">My.CoolStuff.Class, My.CoolStuff</field>
    </fields>
```

I've tried adding storageType="NO" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" to the field but without affect, it remains tozenized and stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and add your computed field to the regular  `<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">` section IN ADDITION to the computed field, and specify an analyzer.

for example:

```xml
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="my multilist field" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <Analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
  </field>
</fieldNames>
```

Comment: The purpose of using a computed field is to avoid storing the guids, and instead store text. Using your suggestion would result in storing guids again.

Comment: Did you try it?  In combination with the computed field, it should store the values as you intend.

Comment: I hadn't tried it - I thought you were suggesting that instead of, rather than adding to the config. Ok I tried it, and it worked :) but I'm confused - what's going on here?

Comment: I clarified the answer a bit. Glad it worked. As to what's happening, I'm not exactly sure. My guess is that the indexType is either ignored or calculated differently with ComputedFields.  I'll dig into it later, as I am also curious. For now, I just know it works.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest one thing for you and it should work:

Create a computed field that replacing the spaces in title field with " _ ", when  you search replace any the space in your search keyword with " _ " so your  it will be like : Little_Hampton